# Implementation of io.ReadWriteSeeker in golang

Tags: go, buffer, seek

Is there an implementation of `io.ReadWriteSeeker` to use in Golang?

Since, `bytes.Buffer` does not implement `Seek` method, I need to find such an implementation to use as a buffer written by `zipwriter` and to be read with seeking.

In addition I wont go with `Reader(buff.Bytes())` to covert with memory copy, because I can not afford double memory size for buffered data.

In addition, when using `os.File` as the option, if I wont call `f.Sync`, it will never touch file system, right? Thanks.

My simplified codes:

```
func process() {
  buff := new(bytes.Buffer)
  zipWriter := zip.NewWriter(buff)
  // here to add data into zipWriter in sequence
  zipWriter.Close()
  upload(buff) // upload(io.ReadSeeker)
}
```

Comment: bytes.Buffer.Bytes does not copy bytes. bytes.Reader implements io.Reader and io.Seeker. Are you sure you need all interfaces in one type? I can only think of os.File from the top of my head.

Comment: Seems when using Reader(buff.Bytes()) it's occupying too much memory, probably caused by the byte slice is going to stack. Yes, i guess i have to use such a type for I can't afford memory for converting between  Writer and ReadSeeker.

Comment: A ReadSeeker necessarily needs a copy of all data. Otherwise seeking to the beginning and/or end is impossible.

Comment: Hi Peter, my case is no more writing after the data is buffered, so it's a full copy before reading.

Comment: Now I understand even less why you need everything in a single type. It's probably best if you include the code you're having trouble with. And, again, bytes.NewReader(buff.Bytes()) does not copy any bytes.

Comment: Hi @Peter, i simplified my codes as above, hope it can explain. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, using the same underlying array for (`uBuf` and `zBuf`) buffers,

```
package main

import (
    "archive/zip"
    "bytes"
    "io"
)

func upload(io.ReadSeeker) {}

func process() {
    zBuf := new(bytes.Buffer)
    zipWriter := zip.NewWriter(zBuf)
    // add data into zipWriter in sequence
    zipWriter.Close()
    uBuf, zBuf := zBuf.Bytes(), nil
    // upload(io.ReadSeeker)
    upload(bytes.NewReader(uBuf))
}

func main() {}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/8TKmnL_vRY9

---

> Package bytes
>
> ```
> import "bytes"
> ```
>
> [func (*Buffer) Bytes](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer.Bytes)
>
> ```
> func (b *Buffer) Bytes() []byte
> ```
>
> Bytes returns a slice of length b.Len() holding the unread portion of
>   the buffer. The slice is valid for use only until the next buffer
>   modification (that is, only until the next call to a method like Read,
>   Write, Reset, or Truncate). The slice aliases the buffer content at
>   least until the next buffer modification, so immediate changes to the
>   slice will affect the result of future reads.

The tuple assignment statement

```
    uBuf, zBuf := zBuf.Bytes(), nil
```

gets the slice descriptor for the zipped bytes (`zBuf.Bytes()`) and assigns it to the slice descriptor `uBuf`. A slice descriptor is a `struct` with a pointer to the underlying array, the slice length, and the slice capacity. For example,

```
type slice struct {
    array unsafe.Pointer
    len   int
    cap   int
}
```

Then, for safety, we assign `nil` to `zBuf` to ensure that no further changes can be made to its underlying array, which is now used by `uBuf`.

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for your perfect answer, i just notice slices are reference types than array, so it's cheap to be passed. In addition, good point setting zBuf to nil for safety.